# How do I build a service control mamager (SCM)-managed driver for windows without PNP?

Tags: windows, driver

I'm new to building windows drivers.

I'm trying to build a windows service control manager (SCM) managed driver for a parallel port and I want to make it SCM-managed without PNP and without trigger the addDevice being called by the PNP manager.
Basically, I need to create a PDO in order to get access to the bus itself.

More information can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/parports/device-stacks-for-parallel-ports-and-devices

Is possible to do this, and if so, where can I find a good code sample of a driver written in this way?

Thanks in advance.
S. Maybisher

Comment: Pleas reword the question header to state the intent.  The current one makes it sound like you want to use a driver, not make one.  I will improve the question, please let me know if it looks acceptable to you.

Comment: Hi, my idea is to learn driver development, therefore I saw a basic driver that is loaded with sc create mydrv command, is started with sc start usermydrv and stopped with sc stop mydrv without need of pnp. mydrv doesn't manage real hardware, but I tough if is possible to use the same idea with some hardware like parallel port write and to avoid all the overhead of pnp for a newbie like me. Thanks.